# mount dvd player wodim

Tags: mount, devices

I got got following error message when I use `wodim --devices` to know the devices and want to mount my device,

What should I do to resolve the error message?
Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

iccsi

```
$ wodim --devices
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```